# Regex Matching for a specific string such as Ord(500) Ord(601) Ord(537)

Tags: regex, string, pattern-matching, string-matching, regexp-replace

I want to find and remove all the strings which matches `Ord(537)` i.e. `Ord ->` followed by round brackets containing any numbers `Ord(537) Ord(616) Ord(631) Ord(709) Ord(717) Ord(600)`

Answer (score 0):

You could use `REGEXP_LIKE` here:

```sql
DELETE
FROM yourTable
WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(col, '(^|\s)Ord\(\d+\)');
```

### Demo